# Unable to install XUnit.runner.devices (not compatible with Net451)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, xunit

It's not possible to install the NuGet package: xunit.runner.devices. The following error occurred:

```
Package xunit.runner.devices 2.2.0 is not compatible with net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) / win-x64. Package xunit.runner.devices 2.2.0 supports:
  - monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
  - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0)
  - xamarinios (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v0.0)   UITestApp.CrossPlatformUITest   C:\MYPATH\UITestApp.CrossPlatformUITest.csproj  1
```

I tried:

- To install different versions of xunit.runner.devices
- .NETFramework
  versions:

  - 4.5.1
  - 4.5.2
  - 4.6.1
  - 4.6.2
  - 4.7
  - 4.7.1
  - 4.7.2

Is there any way to fix this / am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It requires Xamarin or UWP target platforms, as error says. You should create correct test project to install this package

Comment: [There](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started/uwp/devices-runner) is getting started doc from xunit

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was trying to install this package into a Xamarin.UITest project.

Comment: Hi Cornest, per the error message, we can know that this package not support on Xamarin.UITest project, since the project target framework is .NET Framework 4.x, we can right click the project name-Properties to check the target framework, the xunit.runner.devices: https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.devices depends on MonoAndroid 8.1/UAP 10.0/Xamarin.iOS 1.0 which means when we create a project with those target framework, then we can install this package into those projects, sorry for this inconvenience. Meanwhile, you can follow the document that Pavel shared to use this package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have an existing solution with a default Xamarin project. Do you mean that I have to install the package xunit.runner.devices into the Android/iOS/UWP projects?