# Unit test Xamarin Android project business logic

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a problem with Unit testing a Xamarin Android project.

My setup:

- Shared Xamarin project
- ClientX.Android
- ClientX.iOS
- Native.Android
- Native.iOS

Native.Android contains no resources, no MainActivity and no Androidmanifest. It's just shared Mono.Android code and normal business logic for it.

I have an Xunit testing project with which I have been able to test the Shared Xamarin project.

I need to test some business logic that is contained inside Native.Android but I get an error (which does make sense to me):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error NU1201  Project Client.XXXX.NativeDroid is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project
> Client.XXX.NativeDroid supports: monoandroid12.0
> (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)   XXX.UnitTests

I can't find how I should go about Unit tests inside a Xamarin Android project that is not view/UI related.

Comment: Try to create an Android project (i.e. targeting monoandroid12) and add XUnit references there, instead of creating a project from the VS XUnit template. See the comments in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55236452/6292693).

Comment: Check out [this NuGet package](https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit) too.Your problem might be a symptom of bad design: business logic should be platform-agnostic. Can't you relocate it to a .NET standard library?

Comment: You cannot unit test platform specific code as you wouldn't be able to resolve the dependencies. You need to move your business logic outside of the platform projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer.

Using this project: https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit
You can run Platform specific (iOS/Android) unit tests (not UI tests). See the "Integration" folder in that project for examples of projects. Update the dependencies, add the references to the other projects you need inside Visual Studio and it should work for your own Xamarin 5 project.

Comment: Those are device runners which run on device emulators/simulators and real devices. Not really "unit testing" though, because you cannot run this in a CI pipeline as the emulators must be running already when the tests are executed, AFAIK.

Comment: What would you call them then? They are certainly not UI tests, tests that run only on the platform can still be unit tests, the Android runner doesn't need to run the entire app, it should only be able to compile. These are unit tests in my book and they can be run in a pipeline.  [This project](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/DeviceTests) shows how with xunit device runners, build.cake and an azure-pipelines.yml.

Comment: Indeed, they are "sort of" unit test but with a platform dependency, that's why I said "not really", because unit tests shouldn't have any hard dependencies. I'm aware of how it can work, but starting emulators is a finicky thing and requires quite a bit of setup. I'd rather keep the business logic separated to make testing as easy as possible.